# I want to validate date inputs with datepicker that should be validated for the date

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, regex, date

I want to validate date input box and also datepicker that should be validated for the date  like

```
09-30-2016 
09/30/2016
```

But i am able to handle `mm-dd-yyyy` and `mm/dd/yyyy` in input bix but in datepicker in not triggering properly.
My code :

```
function isValidDate(input) {
  var regexes = [
    /^(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})$/,
    /^(\d{1,2})\-(\d{1,2})\-(\d{4})$/ 
  ];

  for (var i = 0; i < regexes.length; i++) {
    var r = regexes[i];
    if(!r.test(input)) {
      continue;
    }
    var a = input.match(r), d = new Date(a[3],a[1] - 1,a[2]);
    if(d.getFullYear() != a[3] || d.getMonth() + 1 != a[1] || d.getDate() != a[2]) {
      continue;
    }
    // All checks passed:
    console.log(input);
    return true;
  }
 return false;

}

$(document).on('blur','.dateValidation',function(){     
  var isValid = isValidDate($(this).val());
  if(!isValid) {
    $('.date_error').html('Invalid date format!'); 
    return false;
  } 
});
$(document).on('click','.date',function(){ 
  alert("test");
    $(this).datepicker({todayHighlight: true,autoclose: true,autoclose: true}).datepicker("show");

});
```

Comment: You are better off only supporting the dd-mm-yyyy format as you'll soon hit the problem of trying to guess what the date for 1116. Is this the 1st Nov or the 11th Jan?

Comment: ok @jeff.  I have another issue actually dd-mm-yyyy and dd/mm/yyyy manual input is working fine. Now when i am using Date Picker its not triggering as i have updated my code above.

Comment: Could you provide more relevant code? HTML, for example.